# Javascript date convert to timezone with format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can i create a date object, then convert to another timzone from a datestring with a timezone and format as below

```
var date="20160317T073000";
var format = "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss";
var timezone ="America/New_York"

var newTimezone="Asia/Kolkata"
```

i want the date to convert to newTimezone, i tried with moment.js, but its converting to browser timezone

```
date=moment(date,format); 
date.tz(timezone);

console.log(moment(date).format());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js seems to have that : http://momentjs.com/timezone/

**Convert Dates Between Timezones**

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

To convert your format, that should do it :

```
'20160317T073000'.replace(/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/, '$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6')
```

Comment: where to specify the date format, my sourceDate format is YYYYMMDDTHHmmss

Comment: Well, it's probably somewhere in the doc, or convert the format yourself. If you know what you've got and what you want to have, it will be easy to transform format